# VueJS - Vue-auth $auth.user() empty after page reload

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js

My VueJS Application works with components. The login works fine. In one of my components I have a function to check the user permission:

```
checkPermissionOnRoute () {
        alert('ddd')
        console.log(this.$auth.user().permission)
        console.log(this.$router)
        if (this.$route.meta.permission) {
          if (!this.$auth.user().permission || !this.$route.meta.permission.includes(this.$auth.user().permission)) {
            console.log(this.$auth.user())
            console.log(this.$auth.user().permission)
            console.log(this.$route.meta.permission)
            console.log('ssrrver')
            this.$router.replace('/server-error')
          }
        }
      },
```

In the compontend I added this:

```
created () {
      this.getUserPermission()
      this.checkPermissionOnRoute()
    },
    watch: {
      '$route': 'checkPermissionOnRoute',
    }
```

So everytime the component changes it checks the permission. If its wrong it redirects to another page.
The component has also on the top: 
But if i make a page reload I can log the user and the data is inside there.
But if I try to log this.$auth.user().permission it is always false, after a page reload. If I navigate through the SPA it works fine.
The strange thing In the function I log:

console.log(this.$auth.user())
    console.log(this.$auth.user().permission)

and the first log has the permission field. But than the second log says false?